# Ruby retrieves only specific hash key defined in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From the following array of hashes I want to leave only the keys defined in the array `a`

```
  test = [{ 'id' => '123',
      'circulating_supply' => '18846675',
      'max_supply' => '21000000',
      'market_cap' => '1165693461932',
      'market_cap_dominance' => '0.4277',
      'num_exchanges' => '393',
      'num_pairs' => '66516',
      'num_pairs_unmapped' => '5168' },
      { 'id' => '321',
      'circulating_supply' => '4121',
      'max_supply' => '324134',
      'market_cap' => '9999',
      'market_cap_dominance' => '0.4204',
      'num_exchanges' => '943',
      'num_pairs' => '2341',
      'num_pairs_unmapped' => '4231' },


a = ['market_cap', 'num_exchanges', 'num_pairs_unmapped']
```

In the result I should get:

```
  test = [{'id' => '123',
      'market_cap' => '1165693461932',
      'num_exchanges' => '393',
      'num_pairs_unmapped' => '5168' },
      {'id' = '321',
      'market_cap' => '9999',
      'num_exchanges' => '943',
      'num_pairs_unmapped' => '4231' },]
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#slice-method) will do this.

> Returns a hash containing only the given keys and their values.

```
hash = { 'circulating_supply' => '18846675',
      'max_supply' => '21000000',
      'market_cap' => '1165693461932',
      'market_cap_dominance' => '0.4277',
      'num_exchanges' => '393',
      'num_pairs' => '66516',
      'num_pairs_unmapped' => '5168' }
a = ['market_cap', 'num_exchanges', 'num_pairs_unmapped']

hash.slice(*a)
```

### Update

```rb
  test = [{ 'id' => '123',
      'circulating_supply' => '18846675',
      'max_supply' => '21000000',
      'market_cap' => '1165693461932',
      'market_cap_dominance' => '0.4277',
      'num_exchanges' => '393',
      'num_pairs' => '66516',
      'num_pairs_unmapped' => '5168' },
      { 'id' => '321',
      'circulating_supply' => '4121',
      'max_supply' => '324134',
      'market_cap' => '9999',
      'market_cap_dominance' => '0.4204',
      'num_exchanges' => '943',
      'num_pairs' => '2341',
      'num_pairs_unmapped' => '4231' },


a = ['market_cap', 'num_exchanges', 'num_pairs_unmapped']

test.map { |entry| entry.slice(*a, "id") }
```

Comment: So sorry, the problem is more complex than I thought. I have updated the question if by some miracle you know how to do it.

Comment: Just map and slice the array.

Comment: But still the `id` key will gone `{ 'id' => '123' }`

Comment: Well, why do you not just add the key `id` to `a`?

Comment: `slice` accepts several values so you can do `entry.slice(*a, 'id')`. See update.

Comment: oh gee, I didn't know! I was already starting to do some `test.map { |entry| { id: entry['id'] }.merge(e.slice(*a)) }`